# How to save file in AppData Administrator User

Tags: c#

I have two projects:

1. Windows Form
2. Windows Service

Windows form project is a Configuration utility where saves a Data.XML in

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);`

The same Windows Form app can Install the `Windows Service` but the Windows Service is always installed using `Administrator` credentials.

When my windows form configuration saves the Data.XML its saved into my current User `AppData` folder and I need it in my Administrator `AppData` Folder because then my `Windows Service` won't be able to find it.

Any clue on how can I get:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

For my Administrator account?

Comment: What about sending your configuration data to your service? In this way, it can update its internal variables and save it to a file it can access for persistence.

Comment: You do not have write access to that.

Comment: @EZI how can I do that?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @VAAA NamedPipes, Remoting, WCF, pure TCP, HttpListener, SignalR ....., choose whichever you like.

Answer (score 0):

> Any clue on how can I get:
>
> Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
>   For my Administrator account?

You can use [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve the folder path for a specific user.

However, by default other users will not have access to that folder.  It would weaken your security model if you allow access for this purpose.

SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData

seems to fit that exact purpose.

> The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by all users.

See [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

If possible, consider refactoring both the service and the WinForms app to use a folder that they both may access.